# Onclick Magento PHP

Tags: magento

I need to click on a button and change an order state. So far I've done this:

```
<?php $_order = $this->getOrder() ?>
<div class="buttons-set">
<p class="btn"><a href="<?php $this->saveState($_order);?>">Button</a></p>
</div>
```

In my php I have:

```
public function saveState($order)
{
   return $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_NEW, true);
}
```

The problem is that every time the phtml loads it executes the saveState function, changing the order state everytime, dont know why. I need to execute the saveState function just where the button is clicked. Please help me with this one, i'm really stuck!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`<a href="<?php $this->saveState($_order);?>">Button</a>` doesn't link to a `saveState()` method. It just executes the `saveState()` method immediately, and links to the return value of `saveState()`, in this case I'm guessing that would just be the string representation of a `sales/order` object.

What you need to do is [create a Controller](http://blog.baobaz.com/en/blog/magento-module-create-your-own-controller) whose action you can link to, via something like

```
<a href="<?php
    echo Mage::getUrl('YourModule/YourController/YourAction')
?>">Button</a>
```

Please note as well that having an "action" in a simple link is generally considered bad practice: it is not [RESTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer).